# Access javascript sqlite in android

Tags: android, cordova

i am new in android phonegap application. i try one phonegap application in android, here i create one database and table and insert value using javascript its working fine, now i want  to retrieve database value in android native. here my code

```
my javascript code:

function loaddb()
{
var db = openDatabase(‘testdb’, ’1.0′, ‘my database’, 2 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function (tx)
{
tx.executeSql(‘CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (_id INTEGER, person_name TEXT, address TEXT)’);

tx.executeSql(‘INSERT INTO person (_id, person_name, address) VALUES(1, “Hardik Trivedi”, “Ahmedabad,Gujarat,India”)’);
tx.executeSql(‘INSERT INTO person (_id, person_name, address) VALUES(2, “Sonam Kapoor”, “Mumbai,Maharashtra,India”)’);
tx.executeSql(‘INSERT INTO person (_id, person_name, address) VALUES(3, “Rajnikanth”, “There is no specific address of him :) “)’);

});
}


my html code:


<html>
<head>
<script src=”db.js”></script>
<script src=”jquery.js”></script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<script language=”javascript”>
$(document).ready(function() {
alert(“Hello”);
loaddb();
});
</script>
</div>
<h4>Hello Friends !!!!!!</h4>
</body >

</html>
```

any possibility is there to retrieve this javascript database in android?

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
 var msg;
 db.transaction(function (tx) {
 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, "foobar")');
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (2, "logmsg")');
 msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
 document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;
});

db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length, i;
msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
 msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p>";
 document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
  }
   }, null);
 });
   </script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="status" name="status">Status Message</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want this select statement in android native, is it possible? create and insert using javascript and select statement should be placed in android native.

Comment: I need the instance of the database created through javascript in android native, so that i could access to its table in android.